# Почему во времени UNIX используется ЗНАКОВОЕ целое, а не беззнаковое?

Tags: время, unix

Интересует вопрос, касающийся так называемой [проблемы 2038 года](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_2038_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).
Почему для кодирования времени Юникс используется именно знаковое целое? Дело в том, что максимальное значение в **знаковом** целом равно **2 147 483 647**, (03:14:08 UTC 19 января 2038). Потом меняется последний бит на единицу, и число становится отрицательным. Отрицательный потенциал всеравно не используется (раз планируют переходить на 64-битную систему кодирования).

Максимальное значение в **беззнаковом** целом равно **4 294 967 295**, т.е. в 2 раза больше.
Т.е. получается, половина потенциала 64-битного не используется. Так бы можно было отсрочить проблему на еще ~60 лет вперед.

В википедии написано: "А приведение time_t в целое без знака может нарушить работу программ, которые вычисляют разницу во времени". Не понимаю, как это может нарушить.

Answer (score 4):

Думаю, потому что отсчет ведется с 0.00 1.1.1970, а иногда бывает нужно иметь дело с датами до этого момента.